# Receiving an Error Message in this "Guess the Word" Game?

Tags: python

I am creating a "guess the word" game in python for my intro to programming class. The word is shown with dashes (-) in place of the vowels. The user is supposed to guess the word based off of a provided hint (the words/hints go together as parallel tuples). The user gets 5 guesses and if the word is guessed correctly, a certain amount of points are awarded. The user can then either choose to keep playing & accumulate points, or quit. The code was working until I added the coding to ask the user if he/she would like to keep playing. What is it that I need to fix in order for it to work?

```
#Clear Screen
print("\n"*50)

import random

#Variables
keep_playing = "y"
round_score = 0
overall_score = 0
new_words = ""
vowels = "AaEeIiOoUuYy"

#Parallel tuples
while keep_playing.lower() == "y":
    guesswords = ("Japan","France","Mexico","Italy","Australia")
    guesshints = ("Sushi comes from here","Croissants come from here","Tacos come from here","Pizza comes from here","Vegemite comes from here") 

#Random
    index = random.randrange(len(guesswords))
    guesses = 5

#Replacing vowels
    for letter in guesswords[index]:
        if letter not in vowels:
            new_words += letter
        else:
            new_words += "-"

#Output        
    print(new_words.center(80, " "))
    print("Hint:",guesshints[index])

    while guesses > 0:
        input_string = "\nGuess the word! You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses remaining: "
        user_guess = input(input_string)
        if user_guess.upper() == guesswords[index].upper():
            print("YOU WIN")
            round_score = (guesses * 2)
            overall_score += round_score
            print("Your score for this round is ",round_score)
            break
        guesses -= 1

    print("Your overall score is ",overall_score)
    keep_playing = input("Would you like to keep playing? (y/n)")   

print("GAME OVER")
```

Comment: Maybe because you have `keep_playing = "yes"`, but to check the for keep playing you use `while keep_playing.lower() == "y":`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even notice that. I fixed that, but it still isn't working the way it should for me.

Comment: Can you then clarify what way you expect it to work? Also you indentation is off here, can you fix that please?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the indentation. Fixing that in my code got most of it to work. When I first play the game, it works perfectly, but then as I move onto the next round, it just sort of builds off of the first one. For example, round 1 will show J-p-n with the hint for Japan and once I guess "Japan", it shows my points & asks if I want to play again. I put "y" to play again, and then it shows my next word as J-p-nFr-n-c- with the hint that goes with France. This continues building off with each round. How can I stop it from building off of each other & just show 1 word per round?

Comment: relocate `new_words = ""` to the beginning of the first while loop.

Comment: That fixed my issue, thank you so much!

Comment: Any time :) . May I make a few suggestions?  guesswords` and `guesshints` can be place outside the loop. In `vowels` it is sufficient to list the lowercase and use `letter.lower()` in the `if`. Alternatively, you can import the package [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) so you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub).